# Compatibility problem on Windows Server 2019

Tags: node.js, windows-services, windows-server-2019, node-windows

For two years now, I created a windows service for my node project on a windows server 2008 using [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) module. Recently we upgrade our version to a Windows Server 2019. I then tried to recreate my service on this new version of Windows Server. I could create the service but it doesn't launch.

I have this message :

> Windows could not start the MyService service on local computer. Error
> 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

I tried to launch it on a Windows Server 2016, and it works correctly. Is there anything I can do to fix that or is it just a compatibility problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After checking errors logged at 'node_project/daemon/appName.err', I found out that a certain module was missing (Error: Cannot find module '@author.io/args'). To fix this, I needed to explicitly downgrade node-windows version to "node-windows": "1.0.0-beta.6" on my package.json file.

Hope this helps. More info here - https://issueantenna.com/repo/coreybutler/node-windows/issues/308